# How extract word from string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table which contains column 'description'.Description contains strings, for example **@abc will have @wxyz**.

I want result {**abc,wxyz**} using sql query.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `@abc` and `@xyz` always will be the same length or It can be different length, but always starts with `@`?

Comment: try to use substring_index

Comment: no.They may have different length.Yes always start with'@'.

Comment: Is it in `sql` or `mysql`? I see both the tags

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl It is in sql

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl *SQL* is Structured Query Language where as *MySQL* is RDBMS. It's different things, so why tags cannot be used together? It was much better when OP provided RDBMS he's using.

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the comment about phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Edited the answer, this might help you

```
SET @Description ='@abcd will have @xyz';
SELECT CONCAT('{',SUBSTRING(@Description, LOCATE('@', @Description), LOCATE(' ', @Description)),',', SUBSTRING( @Description,LOCATE(' @', @Description), LENGTH(@Description) - LOCATE(' @', @Description)), '}');
```

You can replace @Description with your column name! Hope this helps...

Comment: I tried in phpmyadmin but gives error 'FUNCTION dazzle.PATINDEX does not exist'